# Unable to import package org.objectweb.asm

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to compile other developer's open source custom library.
I have compiled or find dependencies but it fails to build in gradle
which was failing to import java's internal library package *org.objectweb.asm*
it's a java internal library so it must be in tools.jar but build.properties it's aleady importing java's tools.jar and aleady applying plugin java so i have no idea

here it's build.properties ( main part)

```
allprojects {
apply plugin: 'java'

group 'com.nemosw.spigot'
version '1.2.21'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
javadoc.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

repositories {
    // junit
    mavenCentral()
    // nms spigot & mox
    mavenLocal()
}
}


project(':core') {
processResources {
    filesMatching('**/*.yml') {
        expand project.properties
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url = 'https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
    maven { url = 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
    flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compileOnly files(Jvm.current().toolsJar)
    compile 'com.nemosw.mox:mox-collections:1.0'
    compile 'com.nemosw.mox:mox-task:1.0'
    compile 'com.nemosw.mox:mox-math:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.nemosw.mox:mox-tools:1.1'
}
}
```

other part's are can be found in here:
https://github.com/nemosrc/tap

also you need to fix some dependencies and compile he's mox library(all of them)

https://github.com/nemosrc/mox-math

https://github.com/nemosrc/mox-tools

https://github.com/nemosrc/mox-collections

https://github.com/nemosrc/mox-task

and tons of error because of the failed library.

> C:\tap\core\src\main\java\com\nemosw\spigot\tap\event\ASMEntityEventExecutor.java:6:
>   error: package org.objectweb.asm does not exist import
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
>                           ^
>
> C:\tap\core\src\main\java\com\nemosw\spigot\tap\event\ASMEntityEventExecutor.java:7:
>   error: package org.objectweb.asm does not exist import
>   org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
>                           ^
>
> C:\tap\core\src\main\java\com\nemosw\spigot\tap\event\ASMEntityEventExecutor.java:8:
>   error: package org.objectweb.asm does not exist import
>   org.objectweb.asm.Type;
>                           ^
>
> C:\tap\core\src\main\java\com\nemosw\spigot\tap\event\ASMEntityEventExecutor.java:15:
>   error: package org.objectweb.asm does not exist import static
>   org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.*;
>                                  ^
>
> C:\tap\core\src\main\java\com\nemosw\spigot\tap\event\ASMEventExecutor.java:9:
>   error: package org.objectweb.asm does not exist import
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you think that it's a Java internal library?

The `org.objectweb.asm` package is part of the ASM library: https://asm.ow2.io/

You might want to add this to your Gradle build: 
`compile group: 'org.ow2.asm', name: 'asm', version: '7.1'`

Comment: thanks alot! i started java about month ago so another noob here haha

Answer (score 4):

You can add dependency in dependencies block -

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compileOnly files(Jvm.current().toolsJar)
    compile 'com.nemosw.mox:mox-collections:1.0'
    compile 'com.nemosw.mox:mox-task:1.0'
    compile 'com.nemosw.mox:mox-math:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.nemosw.mox:mox-tools:1.1'
    compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm:'7.1'
}
```

You can find more dependency from this site
 https://mvnrepository.com/

Answer (score 1):

For some internal APIs, this is a limitation in javac.

You can use this property with javac to make it work
javac -XDignore.symbol.file=true

From Java 9 onwards you can use
javac --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm=ALL-UNNAMED

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 9+?
Create a file called **module-info.java**

```
module com.example.nightmare {
    requires org.objectweb.asm;
}
```

place in root of jar or maybe 'java/main/src/resources'

(your amount of effort or results may vary and will likely need [a bunch more requires](https://www.jrebel.com/blog/java-9-modules-cheat-sheet))

It's an internal class for use by JVM components which may have unexpected changes not only between versions, but unscheduled in patches, so use at your own peril. The recommended approach loads a version from a jar separate from one used by the JVM. I'll surmise keeping it 'internal' adds to the stability in development of the OpenJdk and on the bleeding edge deployments. Any use of such internal components is never recommended.

Of course lots of things are not recommended that we still do. Enjoy!